# Interpolating data at different heights for various times in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a set of data (144 rows and 7 columns). The first column is time and remaining six are temperature at heights 1,2,4,8,16 and 32 m. I would like to interpolate (linearly) between this heights i.e. h = 1:0.5:32. and then finally make a contour plot..
Could anyone please guide me regarding this, as I am doing this for first time in MAtlab..
Any help would be greatly appreciated..
Thanks
Shital

Comment: Take a look at [`interp1()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) and also [this alternative from the FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43325-quicker-1d-linear-interpolation--interp1qr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a linear interpolation per row (see interp1 help at matlab):

```
for lp = 1:size(Data,1)
    DataI(lp,:) = interp1([1 2 4 8 16 32],Data(lp,2:end),h,'linear');
end
```

For your contour plot;

```
figure(1);
contour(Data(:,1), h, transpose(DataI))
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Temperature')
legend('Height')
```

Comment: I tried the interp1 function but it gives me error. I have 144 rows which corresponds to Temperature at 6 heights measured at different times during the day.. I would like to interpolate for the entire length of rows.. Thanks

Comment: X will be time (hours) and Y will be height.. On it will be plotted Temperature..